# How to generalize the file function to open as many text files as provided in parameter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, dictionary, word-frequency

I want to generalize my following code to take as many files in parameters without hardcoding, like f1 and f2 are here. How can i do that?
Here is my code.

```
def wordFreq(f1, f2):
    f1 = open(f1, 'r')  
    f2 = open(f2, 'r')
    file_list = [f1, f2]  
    num_files = len(file_list) 
    wordFreq = {} 

    .....
    .....

    return wordFreq

print(wordFreq('file1.txt','file2.txt'))
```

Comment: input a list of files and open them in a loop, before putting it into `file_list`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [*args](https://pythontips.com/2013/08/04/args-and-kwargs-in-python-explained/)

```
def word_freq(*files):
    file_list = [open(file, 'r') for file in files]
    ...
```